# Why steal my work?

Tags: support

In [an answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/26824/28) to [How to Write A Ragtime Piano Piece?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/26819/28) someone has illegally used content from [my HubPages article](http://hubpages.com/video/How-to-Write-Ragtime-Music-on-the-Piano). There is no credit to the original source, which would have been something, nor has anyone attempted to contact me to ask permission to use it. Please take it down immediately.

Comment: I believe this is the answer in question: http://music.stackexchange.com/a/26824/18837

It's not nice to post sans attribution, and copy-paste is not a good answering technique. This is clearly plagiarism. Good article though @JohnMello. Wish we could welcome you to Music.SE under better conditions.

Answer (score 4):

I have removed the answer in question; it was pretty clearly lifting the majority of your content without any attempt at attribution or following Fair Use guidelines.

In the future, please use the method outlined by Stack Exchange for copyright takedown notices — under point 15 on [this page](http://stackexchange.com/legal).